# html, javascript: scrolling through list box items - and display prompt for each item

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

So what I need to do is the following: when I select an item from list box I need to be able to dynamically display additional information for that item in a separate box. I.e. let's say I'm scrolling through a list of cars, for each car I select I would   display the price, the color, mileage etc. The idea was for this to be similar in look and feel to a prompt that pops up next to the element when the use hovers-over. In other words ideally I'd see a small box that magically pops-up right next to the item with all the required information.
Any recommendations on how to implement that?

Update:
To clarify what I'm looking for. I ended up implementing it by responding to the change() event and manually updating the html element I previously defined for this particula purpose, just like one of the answers below suggests:

```
$('#available-elements').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var element = find_element(id);//retrieve complete element info
    $('#the_prompt').show();
    $('#prompt_name').find('td').text(element.title);
    $('#prompt_datatyp').find('td').text(element.dataType);     
    $('#prompt_groupCode').find('td').text(element.groupCode);
});
```

The prompt element is defined as follows:

```
    <table id="the_prompt" style="border:2px solid grey;">
      <tr id='prompt_name'><td class="rate_prompt"></td></tr>
      <tr id='prompt_datatyp'><td class="rate_prompt"></td></tr>
      <tr id='prompt_groupCode'><td class="rate_prompt"></td></tr>
     </table>
```

But I was hoping there would be a plug-in fro this or something. Especially, I was hoping I would avoid defining a static html element with its pre-defined location, size etc. and updating its content manually. Instead, I'd love to see a prompt, similar to hover-over help, right next to the clicked list element, with the arrow pointing to the clicked element.
I'm still relatively new to jQuery but I've been really impressed with its capabilities and plugins so the idea for the above did not seem that unrealistic to me.

Comment: Show that you tried something **before** asking a question.

Comment: look into [jquery.org](http://jquery.org) and [jqueryUI.com](http://jqueryUI.com)

Comment: Show that I tried? Thank you very much, I am actually in the process of implementing it "manually", i.e. pre-defining a static box and refreshing it on each select but I'm hoping there are better solutions. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Dan- I'm already using jquery. Can you be more specific how jquery/jquerUI might provide advantage to solve this particular problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution shows a description taken from the data attribute in fixed div and also adjusts the position of infobox when hovering over list items:

jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastli = null;
    var ci = $('#carinfo');
    $('.carlist li').hover(function(e){
        if (lastli == this) { return; } else {}
        var top = e.pageY;
        var left = e.pageX;
        if (left+100 > $(window).width()){
            left -= 100;
        }
        ci.html($(this).data('info'));
        ci.css({'top':top, 'left': left}).show();
    },function(e){
        var elt = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget;
        if (elt != this && elt != ci[0]) {
            ci.hide();
            lastli = null;
        } else {
            lastli = this;
        }
    });
    ci.mouseleave(function(e){
        var elt = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget;
        if (elt!=lastli) {
            ci.hide();
            lastli = null;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML sample:

```html
<ul class="carlist">
    <li data-info="2004 Ford Ranger XLT 2.3L 2WD 125758 miles $5,988">
        2004 Ford Ranger
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="carinfo"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
ul.carlist { 
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}

ul.carlist li {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#eef;
}

#carinfo {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    background-color: white;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/WEek7/)

Comment: Thanks @Stano, that's exactly the effect I was hoping to achieve.

Comment: Nice answer Stano! I love being able to see the solution running in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

jquery can handle the updating of the html label in a popup or on the existing html page like this:

```
       <div class="highlight"><label>Car Info:</label>
                <label id="carinfo" for="carinfo"></label>
        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#yourlist_id').change(function () {
            var selectedCar = $(this).val();
            //I don't know how you want to get the car info 
            //if you have a function that returns that data it would be
            //something like this:
            var carInfo = getCarInfo(selectedCar);
           $("label[for='carinfo']").text(carInfo); });

      });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Thomas that's more or less what I did. I was hoping there would be a plugin for this though, please see my updated question.